# simplify this array (php) json output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having trouble on formatting my json. Basically I have this script structure,

```
$array1 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++)
{
$array1[] = array
(
    "stocks" => array
    (
    "0" => "apple" 
    "1" => "banana"
    "2" => "mango"
)
);
}
```

When executed, this outputs (in JSON format):

```
{
    stocks:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    }
}

{
    stocks:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    }
}
```

My problem is, what changes do I have to make to produce an output like this:

```
{
    stocks:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    },

    stocks:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want two items to have the same key?  I don't believe that's exactly possible.

Comment: What you want to achieve is incorrect JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest format would be the following:

```
$array1 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++)
{
    $array1['stocks'][] = array
    (
             "0" => "apple" 
             "1" => "banana"
             "2" => "mango"
    );
 }
```

which will display output like:

```
{
    stocks: [
        {
            0 : apple,
            1 : banana,
            2 : mango
        },
        {
            0 : apple,
            1 : banana,
            2 : mango
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array keys has to be unique. If they're not, the values of the current item will get overwritten each iteration within the for loop.

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++) {
    $arr["stocks{$i}"] = array(
        "0" => "apple" 
        "1" => "banana"
        "2" => "mango"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two elements in an array (or object) that have the same key. If you want to have them both in one array, you'll have to assign separate keys to each of them, like this:

```
$array1 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++)
{
    $array1["stocks{$i}"] = array
    (
        "0" => "apple" 
        "1" => "banana"
        "2" => "mango"
    );
}
```

Which would output:

```
{
    stocks0:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    },

    stocks1:
    {
        0 : apple,
        1 : banana,
        2 : mango
    }
}
```